# Access Query to txt file without column names.

Tags: ms-access, export

I have an access query which creates some output, 3 columns named e.g. *A*, *B*, and *C*.

I would like to create a function where I can automatically output this query to a text file without the header rows. I am currently outputting the file to excel then opening the file and deleting the first row. The user then has to convert from excel to text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the TransferText method:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim,,"myQuery", "D:\temp\myquery.txt"
```